# Dynamically add values from different json responses - JS

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

I am calling an API and getting the total_tweet_count. If the meta tag contains a next_token, I fetch the next API (here I call the corresponding object) with the next_token and push the total_tweet_count to an array. However, if the response doesnt contain a next_token, I stop iterating and just push the total_tweet_count and return the array. For some reason, the code doesnt seem to run. Please help.

The below example should get the next_token from res1 and call res2 and push the tweet_count into the array. Then using the next_token of res2, fetch res3 data and push the count. Since res3 doesnt have a next_token, we end the loop and return the data. This is the expectation. Please advice.

```js
const getData = async () => {
  const totalCount = [];
  const results = await Promise.resolve(data.res1);
  totalCount.push(results.meta.total_tweet_count)
  do {
    const results1 = await Promise.resolve(data[`res${results.meta.next_token}`]);
    totalCount.push(results1.meta.total_tweet_count)
  }
  while (results.meta.next_token)
  return totalCount;
}

getData().then(res => console.log(res))
```

The final output I expect is [1,20, 8]

Please advice.

Fiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/czmwtj3e/

Comment: I suggest you read [Using Promises on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).

Comment: If I use promises individually, it works. Is there something wrong with my do.. while?

Comment: A suggestion: You should just show people necessary data and remove other unrelated data.

Comment: Could you [edit] your post and show us an example of you using Promises individually?

Comment: Sorry. Edited the post and removed unwanted code

Answer (score 0):

Your loop condition is constant:

```
  const results = await Promise.resolve(data.res1);
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  …
  do {
    …
  }
  while (results.meta.next_token)
```

What you are looking for is

```
const getData = async () => {
  const totalCount = [];
  let results = await Promise.resolve(data.res1);
  totalCount.push(results.meta.total_tweet_count)
  while (results.meta.next_token) {
    results = await Promise.resolve(data[`res${results.meta.next_token}`]);
    totalCount.push(results.meta.total_tweet_count)
  }
  return totalCount;
}
```

or

```
const getData = async () => {
  const totalCount = [];
  let results = {meta: {next_token: 1}};
  do {
    results = await Promise.resolve(data[`res${results.meta.next_token}`]);
    totalCount.push(results.meta.total_tweet_count)
  }
  while (results.meta.next_token)
  return totalCount;
}
```

Notice there is no `const results1` in either of these, but an assignment to the mutable `results` variable.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell:

- `getData()` is a wholly synchronous process acting on `data` therefore does not need to be an `asyncFunction`.
- the required array of tweet counts can be created with a combination of [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).
- the `.next_token` property does not need to be used (unless it has some secret meaning beyond what has been explained in the question).

```
const getData = () => {
    const keys = Object.keys(data); // array ['res1', 'res2',  'res3'] 
    const totalCounts = keys.reduce((arr, key) => { // iterate the `keys` array with Array.prototype.reduce()
        arr.push(data[key].meta.total_tweet_count); // push next tweet count onto the array
        return arr; // return `arr` to be used in the next iteration
    }, []); // start the reduction with empty array
    return totalCounts; // [1, 20, 8]
};
```

In practice, you would:

- pass `data` to the function
- avoid intermediate variables

```
    const getData = (data) => {
        return Object.keys(data).reduce((arr, key) => {
            arr.push(data[key].meta.total_tweet_count);
            return arr;
        }, []);
    };
```

Comment: This is just a mock data. Actual api will return only res1. I have to use next-token to call the api agIn to get the next set of data

Comment: Then the mock data is misleading and a full explanation needs to be provided in the question.

Comment: `await Promise.resolve(data.res1);` gives no clue that a call to the API is made. It implies promise wrapping of synchronously available data.

Comment: Yeah. Just mocking up an API. This is the one. https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/9956214/T1LMiT5U#59b36932-1a57-4b72-b223-245520ff0b63